# setup an aws api gatway with serverless

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I built out my dev environment manually, I wanted to focus on logic and skip the learning curve on serverless, but before deploying to prod I want to standardize and parameterize my stack.

setting up my dynamodb tables has been straight forward, but I'm running into snags with deploying a new api-gateway.

I've been using aws codebuild to package layers for lambda functions and an s3 bucket to store my lambda code.

Let's take my dev-rest-auth api (custom authentication) as an example.
I have several resources for login/out, passwords and registration; most are protected by a custom authorizer (login/logout aren't) and all have cors policies. I'm using a custom domain `account-api.dev.example.com` I use several dynamodb tables for housing user data (let's avoid security discussions please, I'm not storing raw passwords and am encrypting using leading industry standards) and temporary codes (password reset & account verification).

to test serverless implementation I'd like to build a yaml file that recreates my existing infrastructure - so the first question is -- is that possible? `Can I parameterize the deployment of an API gateway, with custom authorizer, custom domain, and several lambdas?`

Next question is how?

Organizationally I'm breaking out my yml files by resource:

[image: serverless file tree]

I have several dynamodb yml files that look like this:

```
Resources:
  UserTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      TableName: ${self:custom.resource-prefix}-UserTable-${self:custom.stage}
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: email
          AttributeType: S

      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: email
          KeyType: HASH
      # Set the capacity to auto-scale
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

This was a much earlier attempt (several months ago, from googling, but I don't remember where I found it or what it does) of standing up an API gateway:

```
Resources:
  SharedGW:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: SharedGW

Outputs:
  apiGatewayRestApiId:
    Value:
      Ref: SharedGW
    Export:
      Name: SharedGW-restApiId
  apiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId:
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - SharedGW
        - RootResourceId
    Export:
      Name: SharedGW-rootResourceId
```

I pull everything together in a `serverless.yml` file that references the resource files like this:

```
...
resources:
  # S3 Bucket
  - ${file(resources/s3/s3-static-host.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/s3/s3-CodeBuildResults.yml)}

  # DynamoDB
  - ${file(resources/dynamodb/dynamodb-mealtable.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/dynamodb/dynamodb-ziptable.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/dynamodb/dynamodb-usertable.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/dynamodb/dynamodb-passwordresettable.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/dynamodb/dynamodb-accountregistrationtable.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/dynamodb/dynamodb-restaurant_table.yml)}

  # DNS Records (Route 53)
  # TODO: Determine why DNS hangs
  # - ${file(resources/route_53/dev_dns.yml)}

  # Gateways
   - ${file(resources/api_gateway/local_rest_auth.yml)}
  # - ${file(resources/api_gateway/rest_auth.yml)}
...
```

I've seen several examples of connecting a lambda to a gateway, but it's not clear where the gateway is being created), it's also not clear how the lambda is being created/if I'd be able to reference layers/function code in s3.

I've seen some tutorials for doing this with aws amplify via the cli, but my dream-state would be that I could effectively create a new aws account, deploy this serverless and have my site up and running automatically - with just a little route 53 work to point to a new domain.